# Android inflate ConstraintLayout outside Activity

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, game-development, layout-inflater

I've read several topics about inflaters outside Activities but the solutions proposed have not worked.I don't have any error, the `ConstraintLayout` just does not show itself.

Here is what I want to do :

I am developing a game (the screen orientation is 'landscape'), so I have created a `GameView` in which there is the run loop, and I divide the screen into two parts on the canvas (no fragment) :

- at the left, the game screen. Its dimensions are : `height = screen_height`, `width = game_width`
- at the right, I want to draw a toolbar (a `ConstraintLayout`) containing some stuff (the direction arrows, user info,...)

I initialize the toolbar in the constructor and draw it in the draw function.

The toolbar XML code is :

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
     android:background="@color/light_brown
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!-- ImageViews, Buttons -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code of the `GameView` :

```java
public class GameWorldView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    private ConstraintLayout toolbar = null;
    // ... and other attributes

    // constructor
    public GameWorldView(Context context, int screen_x, int screen_y) {
        //... do some stuff

        toolbar = new ConstraintLayout(context);
        toolbar.layout(0,0,width,height);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffff")); //cyan

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ConstraintLayout inner_toolbar = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_layout, toolbar,false);
        toolbar.addView(inner_toolbar);
    }

    // draw on the canvas
    private void draw(){
        if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            // ... draw everything and then the toolbar

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(x_begin, 0);
            toolbar.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

I see the cyan rectangle at the right place (when I don't set the background color I see the color of the `GameView` that I have set in the 'draw' function), but it does not show the "toolbar" layout I have inflated.

I have tried different things I have seen on other posts such as :

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

or trying to define the toolbar as a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ConstraintLayout`.

I think the problem is about the three lines about the inflater but I have found them on other posts trying to solve a problem similar to mine...

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add the toolbar  to the main layout

Comment: @Thompsonsparta I don't have a main layout since everything is drawn on a canvas : I have a GameWorld activity (launched when the user presses the button 'play' on my first activity) and I display an instance of my GameView class via setContentView. Everything is drawn in the function 'draw' that my instance of GameWorld class uses.

Comment: @Thompsonsparta is `toolbar.draw(canvas)` not enough ?

Comment: not enough add it like ((ViewGroup)this.getRootView()).addView(toolbar);

Comment: @Thompsonsparta it doesn't work, it says the rootView is a gameView... I have tried to add the gameView to a linearLayout but it still says the rootView is a gameView... so it cannot cast the rootView to a ViewGroup

Comment: ((ViewGroup)this.getParent()).addView(toolbar); what about this?

Comment: @Thompsonsparta getParent() returns null

Comment: I have given a linearlayout as parameter in the gameview constructor so that I can do `linearlayout.addview(toolbar)` but it is not really a beautiful code, and I have to delete the `toolbar.draw(canvas)` because addView already draws the view, and it works. Why do I have to addView() to the root or parent if I just want to draw a view on the canvas, ignoring the parent/child hierarchy ?

Comment: Because just declaring a view does not automatically render on to the screen unless its added to an existing viewgroup or drawn to a canvas

Comment: @Thompsonsparta yes I agree, that is why I don't know why `toolbar.draw(canvas)` does not work, it must draw the layout, doesn't it ? When I declare toolbar in my gameView contructor, I set the toolbar background color 'cyan' and the cyan rectangle is drawn on the screen but not the buttons and images written on the xml file